# Stacked full-width buttons

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using stacked full-width buttons in a `DialogFragment`. In version 6.0 devices, all is working, but in version 4.4 it does not show all the buttons (only the first one). Where is the problem?

Comment: Material design is compatible with android which is above 5.0 (lollipop). Therefore it will provide some unexpected designs for below 5 devices

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you more easily

Comment: Specifically, it would be helpful to know what import you are using for `AlertDialog` if you are using that with your DialogFragment.

Comment: I can suggest using following library for material design dialogs - https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs. Note, that latest version migrated to androidx, so you might want to use older version.